# Error while rebasing the changes from SVN to Azure repos git using svn2git tool

Tags: git, rebase, svn2git

We have recently migrated the code from SVN to git using svn2git tool svn2git SVN_REPOSITORY_URL --no-minimize-url --notrunk --nobranches --notags --metadata --authors  --exclude 'EXCLUDE_LIST'. And now we have some new checkins in SVN which we want to rebase it to Azure repo. But while doing that using svn2git --rebase -v we are getting error as
**Migrating from a git-svn v1 layout... Data from a previous version of git-svn exists**

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the revision map (stored in `.git/svn`) wasn't generated or somehow got deleted. As long as it finished with `Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout` then you should be okay.